# what is the difference between ~려고 하다 and ~ㄹ터이다?

Tags: grammar

My dictionary says that ~ㄹ터이다 means intend to ((do)); will ((do)); have a mind to ((do)); mean to ((do)) which I think is the same meaning implied by ~려고 하다

Are the two expression synonyms? What is the difference between them?

Example sentence from the dictionary:
3시까지는 돌아올 터이다

Is it the same as saying 3시까지는 돌아오려고 해요?

Answer (score 2):

'터' as a light noun (`의존 명사`) preceded by attributive (`관형 어미`) '-ㄹ' works very similar to '-ㄹ 것', but much less commonly used. 
Than being said, not only '-ㄹ 터' can express an intention or will, it can also express an anticipation or a fixed plan. Thus, the sentence `3시까지는 돌아올 터이다` can be interpreted into different meanings.

> - I will return by 3.
> - I expect it would return by 3.
> - (By its schedule,) it would return by 3.

(Only the first case is synonymous to '-려고 하다'.)

Note that unlike '-ㄹ 것', '-ㄹ 터' does not work as a complete noun phrase; it's always followed by copula (`서술격 조사`) '이-(다)'.

> - 그 사람이 돌아 올 것이다
> - 그 사람이 돌아 올 터이다.
> - 그 사람이 돌아 올 것은 예상 못 했다
> - *그 사람이 돌아 올 터는 예상 못 했다.

Comment: When '터' is preceded by attributive '-ㄴ', it means circumstance/situation. See 2nd definition in [Naver dict](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=39361400) for examples. In this case, it is not necessarily followed by the copula.